facing issue while deleting file from Download directory on android 12 or more
I am facing an issue while deleting files from the Download directory on Android 12 or more
can anyone help me resolve this issue?
Code
bool statusFileExists = await status.exists();
if (!statusFileExists) {
  debugPrint("File does not exist at path: $statusPath");
  return true;
}

debugPrint("file exists: $statusFileExists");
debugPrint(" file exists on '$statusPath'");
debugPrint("stat: ${await status.stat()}");
if (await Permission.storage.request().isGranted) {
  await status.delete(recursive: true); // this line is throwing exception
}

Exception
Exception has occurred.
PathNotFoundException (PathNotFoundException: Deletion failed, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Download/Saved Statuses/IMG_20240630_100000.jpg' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2))

AndroidManifest.xml file
manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />

    <application
        android:label="status_saver"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
        <activity

actual reference
